# SOAP Reponse contains &gt and &lt instead of < and >

Tags: c#, xml, soap, httpwebrequest

I have a problem with xml result when i use "WebRequest". But i can get correct xml format if i use web reference in project. I can't use web reference in my project some limitation. what wrong and what should i do on this. Here is code and result.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://xxx:xx/service.asmx ");
request.Method = "POST";
XmlDocument _xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
_xmlDoc.Load(_inputPath);
string postData = _xmlDoc.OuterXml;
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
request.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseFromServer);
System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
using (System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(buffer))
{
    System.Xml.XmlReader _reader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(stream);
    ds.ReadXml(_reader);
    ds.WriteXml(_result);
    ds.Dispose();
}
**result for above code**
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <QueryDataSetXMLStringResponse xmlns="sctt.Service">
      <QueryDataSetXMLStringResult>&lt;NewDataSet&gt;
  &lt;Table&gt;
    &lt;GRN_No&gt;GRN-15040089&lt;/GRN_No&gt;    
&lt;/NewDataSet&gt;</QueryDataSetXMLStringResult>
    </QueryDataSetXMLStringResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

**Expected result and get this if i use web refrences**
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <GRN_No>GRN-15040089</GRN_No>    
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>

Request Env and body
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <QueryDataSetXMLString xmlns="sctt.Service">
      <Date>07Jul2015</Date>
    </QueryDataSetXMLString>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the return type of your web method to XmlDocument

```
[WebMethod]
        public XmlDocument getXML() {
            XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
            xml.LoadXml("<xml msg='hello'/>");
            return xml;
        }
```

Comment: Hi, web service is provide by other party. I can't tell them to change it.

Comment: Hmm, I see.  Looks like you'll have to convert it back to XML on your end then.  The method you call it with won't change the server output.  Good luck.

Comment: Sure! I consume web service at my site.